# Is it possible for jobs to communicate directly with each other?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to find a way to spin up a small docker compose  based server, but keep the logs related to running tests separate from the logs from the tests.

Reasons being I don't want a failed app startup to cause a "run tests" workflow to fail (as opposed to be skipped), and the logs are *extremely* lengthy and hard to sift through. Lots of steps start running together after a while.

In terms of UI, the way to do this seems to be to have multiple jobs - one job to start it up, one job to run tests. The server job would have to wait for the test job to complete before terminating.

However, GitHub seems dead-set on jobs being kept compartmentalized. The only solutions I've come up with are bad ones:

- open a port on the self-hosted runners and have Job B access Job A by IP address
- run as services (requires basically duplicating the docker-compose file and is prone to getting out of sync, might swallow log output (?) )
- Run docker inside docker to try and have simultaneous actions running in one runner (this would end up being one job, which defeats the purpose)
- build job + server/test job (while this is marginally better than all-in-one, the server failing to start would still look like a test failure at first glance)
- get a K8S cluster set up, which I would have to ask the Devops team for and they'd probably decline (not to mention it would be way harder to tear down properly), but that would allow sequential operation

Really, I want to run Job A, and rather than terminating, just continue with Job B where Job A ended. So Job A would build and start the server, Job B would run the tests, and then both would complete roughly simultaneously. I don't think this is possible, though.

Are there *any* other ways to pull this off without having the server and test in the same job or doing something from my list above?